# How connect my GoPro Hero 4 camera live stream to openCV using Python?

Tags: python, opencv, gopro

I 'm having troubles trying to capture a live stream from my new GoPro Hero 4 camera and do some image processing on it using openCV.

Here is my trial (nothing shows up on the created window

```
import cv2
import argparse
import time
import datetime
from goprohero import GoProHero


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-a", "--min-area", type=int, default=500, help="minimum    area size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

camera = cv2.VideoCapture("http://10.5.5.9:8080/gp/gpControl/executep1=gpStream&c1=restart")
time.sleep(5)

cv2.namedWindow("", cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

firstFrame = None
noOfCars = 0
speed = 80

while True: 
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
    text = "Smooth"
    print("Capturing ...")

    if not grabbed:
        print("nothing grabbed")
        break
```

the loop breaks as grabbed always equals false which means openCV got nothing.

Answer (score 3):

For those wondering I was able to get a good stream on OpenCV:

First you'll need to download the GoPro Python API, if you have pip:

```
pip install goprocam
```

if not

```
git clone https://github.com/konradit/gopro-py-api
cd gopro-py-api
python setup.py install
```

Then run the following code in a python terminal window:

```
from goprocam import GoProCamera
from goprocam import constants
gopro = GoProCamera.GoPro()
gopro.stream("udp://127.0.0.1:10000")
```

This will re-stream the UDP stream to localhost, FFmpeg is needed on the path!

Then you can use OpenCV to open the localhost stream:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from goprocam import GoProCamera
from goprocam import constants
cascPath="/usr/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
gpCam = GoProCamera.GoPro()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("udp://127.0.0.1:10000")
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("GoPro OpenCV", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

See further examples [here](https://github.com/KonradIT/gopro-py-api/tree/master/examples/opencv_gopro) - you can even use pure [OpenCV to open the stream](https://github.com/KonradIT/gopro-py-api/blob/master/examples/opencv_gopro/ffmpegless-preview.py) although I don't recommend it because its very laggy this way, ffmpeg > localhost > opencv is very stable compared to opencv only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code used to restream UDP to localhost repeatedly throws this error for me, `[mpegts @ 0x7f981b801400] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1432431)`, with increasing dts values. Do you have any insight to the cause?

Comment: How can we do this for Go Pro 9? It doesn't work for go pro 9.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not choosing a literal stream to capture video from. Your ip from the videocapture object must contain an extension on the end, whether it's .jpg or .mpeg (I'd prefer using this), or a few others listed in the documentation. If you use a literal video stream (such as the .mpeg instead of a picture), you should do cv.grab then cv.retrieve. this goes for all ip cameras.
Hope this helped :)