# How can Gopro cam be connected using VideoCapture of opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

Visual Studio and opencv are using versions 2019 and 4.4.0

GoPRO HERO 7 BLACK is connected to PC using USB-C.

I try to open the cam using VideoCapture(), but it is not opened.

Below is the code are using.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc.h>>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
   VideoCpature webcam_01(0);
   if(!webcam_01.isOpened()) {
      cout << "Cam opened error" << endl;
      return -1; }

   while(1) {
      Mat frame;
      webcam_01.read(frame);
      if(frame.empty()) {
        cout << "frame empty" << endl;
        break;
      }
      imshow("img", frame);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't access Gopro like a usb webcam ... you'll need to stream using https://pypi.org/project/goprocam/   and read that stream address using  VideoCpature ("Stream__address")

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Is there a website where I can get a simple example of streaming to a pypi?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112313/how-connect-my-gopro-hero-4-camera-live-stream-to-opencv-using-python

Comment: How you cant open? Do you get any errors? Does it output as "Cam opened error" ?

Comment: An error occurred in the part "if (!webcam_01.isOpen()".
"Camera Opened Error" message will be printed.

Comment: This camera is not a webcam. It has its own sdk you cant open it like this. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112313/how-connect-my-gopro-hero-4-camera-live-stream-to-opencv-using-python).

Comment: Can VideoCapture() is open only usb webcam?

Comment: VideoCapture opens webcam and some usb cameras. The cameras ,which has their own software developement kit(SDK) or has their own api, VideoCapture cant open them